# how to print page with its content size not in full size as a4

Tags: java, php, jquery, html, css

I wanna print an invoice with its auto page size and whats happening is the height of the page is using as A4 size which is not correct. It should be as per the content size. Below I have attached two example in the first one you will see I am getting print in full height which is A4 and totally incorrect and what i want is to print it out with its content height and width as I have shown in the second image below, pls have a look.[image]

Comment: What size paper does the printer use?

Comment: its taking A4 size doesn't matter how much content i have its still taking a4 size, and the space below the content will be blank as i have shown in the image above